# Поделиться в Facebook [iOS 7]

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook, ios7

Доброе время суток, ситуация такая: есть textField, как мне информацию с textField рассказать в Facebook? И что для этого нужно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Доброе время суток уважаемый!

- Вам нужно - это добавить фреймворк: "**Social.framework**";
- Импортировать "**Social/Social.h**";
- В файле **.h** объявить SLComposeViewController *slComposeViewController //название может быть произвольное;
- Сама реализация:

---

```
//Допустим наш textView/Field называется "textViewDetailNotes".
// .m
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
{
     slComposeViewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];            
     [slComposeViewController setInitialText:[[self textViewDetailNotes] text]];

     [self presentViewController:slComposeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
     [[self textViewDetailNotes] resignFirstResponder];
}          
else
{
     //Если пользователь не авторизован в Настройки/Facebook
}
```

Comment: Уважаемый @Ковальский, спасибо за помощь! Всё работает :)

Comment: @leonid3452, Не за что!